# Insert template into new sheet Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-office

**Problem:**

I have created a one-sheet template with .xltm extension that includes a footer, header, and altered font. I want that when creating/adding a new sheet, the settings should be the same as in the created template.I saved this template in the path `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

**I found the following [code](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win016.htm):**

```
Sub Select_The_Sheet_Template()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant

    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    MyPath = Application.TemplatesPath
    ChDrive MyPath
    ChDir MyPath

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Templates (*.xlt*),*.xlt*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Sheets.Add Type:=FileToOpen
    End If

    ChDrive SaveDriveDir
    ChDir SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

When I add a new worksheet the appearance is default, not modified from the template.

**Question:**

How should I modify the code so that when I add a new sheet it has the settings from the template I created? I want it to work when I press the "+" sign which creates a new sheet.

Comment: Do you have a personal add-in that opens each time Excel opens (where you could have your functions handy)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this, but I have created macro files on the "C:\Data" drive, which always open when I open excel (in the settings I have chosen the path from where to open the files on startup). There are functions written in them, for calculating some physical values.

Comment: In short, you cannot achieve this by just modifying your code. It's kind of complicated and I'm not so familiar with it: you need to have a file always open (I have an add-in) where you will create a class module that you will use to store the `App_NewWorkbook` event and another module where you will initialize application events. In the event code, you could close the newly added workbook and call your code if it works correctly. Try to search for `Application.NewWorkbook event`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about templates, but you could just open the template workbook and copy the sheet to your workbook.  That's what this code does.  I've added comments to all the new lines.

```
Sub Select_The_Sheet_Template()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    
    Dim wbTemplate As Workbook ' a varaible to manipulate the template workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet ' a variable to keep track of a worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveSheet ' remember which sheet is active before the template is opened
    
    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    MyPath = Application.TemplatesPath
    ChDrive MyPath
    ChDir MyPath

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Templates (*.xlt*),*.xlt*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen) 'open the template
        wbTemplate.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=sht ' copy the first sheet of the template just after the activesheet
        wbTemplate.Close False 'close the template
    End If

    ChDrive SaveDriveDir
    ChDir SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

Comment: I want the settings from the template to be applied to the new sheet when I press the "+" button at the bottom of the Excel window. The way it works now is that I have to manually activate the macro and the desired given file.

Comment: Do you want to choose the template or just apply a particular template?  Can the template you want just be a hidden sheet in the workbook itself or does it need to be locates somewhere that multiple workbooks can access it?

Comment: 1) I want just apply a particular template. 2) I prefer the template to be in a place where multiple workbooks can access it, although if this is impossible to do, please present a version with a hidden sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that my Prior answer did not really address what you were asking.  Here's another try.  I'll show a couple of examples.  The first one a self-contained example that assumes you have a worksheet in the current workbook named "template".  When you click the plus button to create a new sheet, it will make a copy of the template, including all formatting, data, headers, footers, etc. instead of giving you a blank worksheet.  This code must be put in the module named "ThisWorkbook" as seen in the following image.

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    On Error GoTo enable_events
    Dim sheet_name As String
    sheet_name = Sh.Name
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' code to add new workwheet without re-triggering this event handler
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy after:=Sh
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sh.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Name = sheet_name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 enable_events:
   
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    

End Sub
```

This example calls your existing procedure to allow you to choose the template, which has the worksheet.  You mentioned that your existing code does not bring in your template, so you may want to try to modify it using code from my prior answer.  Like the other code example in this answer, this code needs to be in the "ThisWorkbook" module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    On Error GoTo enable_events
    Dim sheet_name As String
    sheet_name = Sh.Name
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' code to add new workwheet without re-triggering this event handler
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Select_The_Sheet_Template ' call your existing code

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sh.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Name = sheet_name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
enable_events:
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    

End Sub
```

Here's one more example that reads the template from a workbook in a fixed location so any workbook with this code on its "ThisWorkbook" module could get the template.  This example also traps for an error, re-enabling the event handler in case of an error after the event handling is turned off for the workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    
    On Error GoTo enable_events
    
        Dim template_path As String
        template_path = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\TemplateSheet.xltm"
        Dim wb As Workbook
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(template_path)
        wb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=Sh
        wb.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sh.Delete
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
enable_events:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible that for solution #2. not to select a given template from the list, but that when pressing the "plus button" it creates a worksheet from a template with the name and path: "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\TemplateSheet.xltx"?

Comment: Yes, I've added an example of that and also updated with some error handling code.  If this does the trick, I'll appreciate an up vote on each answer.

Comment: The way it works now is that I open a new excel window -> select the template that contains the macro (.xltm) -> add new sheets that have the setting as the file from the path I specified (.xlt) in the macro. However, when I want to save the file, I have to save it already with .xlsm extension. Is it possible to save file with extension .xlsx? I have created other macro files on the "C:\Data" drive (there are some functions written in them), which always open when I open excel. Is there an option to make the created template read in the same way, so that I can save the files with .xlsx?

Comment: What I mean is that when I save the file as .xlsx, I can re-add sheets with formatting from the template. Then the file would use the macro file from the path "C:\Data" (what I wrote in the comment above).

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  The code I gave you that adds a copy of the template sheet when you click the plus sign to add a sheet runs a macro **because** a sheet gets added the workbook.  I know of no way to invoke VBA when a worksheet gets added without out putting VBA in the workbook to which the new sheet is added.  However,  you could put a button in the ribbon that adds a new sheet based on the template.  If the code is invoked from the ribbon, then you could add sheets to based on a template and keep the workbook formatted as an xlsx file

Comment: How to do what you wrote about? I mean adding a button to the ribbon that will add a sheet based on the template? **EDIT:** Is it possible to make it add the sheet based on the template I choose? This would work analogous to one of the versions you suggested.

Comment: It is a bit involved.  Here's a video where I taught my college class about this topic https://vba-course.blogspot.com/2021/08/creating-custom-ribbons-and-addins.html

Comment: Referring to my previous comment: every time I start Excel I automatically load macro files from a specific path (in my case it is "C:\Data") - you can set the path in excel settings. I have created functions in these files to calculate some physical quantities. Is it possible to create a macro file in the same location "C:\Data" which would be related to adding a new worksheet? **Example:** If template "english-ver.xlt" was opened, then the new sheet will be from file "eng-sheet.xlt"; elseif "spain-ver.xlt" was opened, then add from file "spain-sheet.xlt"; else open default sheet version.

Comment: This is possible. but you should ask this as another question.  I have to go to work just now, but I'll answer it when I can.  Others may beat me to it..

Comment: I created a new question. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71559342/adding-a-new-sheet-with-template-settings-excel-vba